# OOP : Trying to design a good class structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Follow up code snippet review question I posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143576/oop-designing-class-inheritances

This is homework so off the bat I am not asking to do it for me but to clarify for me so that I understand.

Here is what the assignment said about the program I have to write:

**Required:**
Write an OO Python Program showing how your sub-classes inherit from the super-class(es) You can have one class (preferred but not a must) or two or more super classes.

What I have to do is write a oo python program showing sub-classing inherited by a class or two or more superclasses. The program has to be about shapes. As an example of what I mean by that is:

Shape: Square

Attributes:

- length
- width

Methods:

- area
- perimeter

I have more shapes of course but from that I find the common attributes and methods from all the shapes and make superclasses and sup-classes.

My super classes are like: 2dShapes, circles and 3dShapes. My sub-classes are like length and width. My methods are area and perimeter. Note I am rambling at this point. The code snippet below does not show this instead I was thinking about making a superclass for attributes and methods and than sub-classes for the shapes? maybe?

Question: is this a good class structure? Is there a better way to structure the classes here? Here is an example of what I'm thinking about how to do this.

```
class Shapes(attributes):
    def __init__(self):
        attributes.__init__(self)
        # not sure how to go on to make the attributes like height and length, radius ect. Maybe like this???
    def height(self):
        raise NotImplementedError # again this program is not supose to actually do anything. The program is just for us to understand inheritance with classes and super classes.

class 2dShapes(Shapes):
    class Square(self):
        def height(self):
            # ???
```

So at this point I am so confused about where to start. Also I am super new to python so be gentle to me  :p

Comment: That's a class inheriting from another class.  What are you confused about?

Comment: Good job being open and constructive about a homework:) Yet you'll probably have to make your question more localized. Is there a specific question you have? Also: you're saying "*My sub-classes are like length and width*", but that wouldn't make much sense and that's not what your snippet indicates. Also: do you really want to nest those classes in the bottom block? Finally, are you aware that `attributes` should be a class itself if you write it this way?

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank-you. my specific question is how to make a good class design for the attributes and methods with out being repetitive.

Comment: clarify the problem please.

Comment: I believe the standard way would be to have one level of classes (call them superclasses if you will) that are 2d and 3d shapes. These can be subclassed to circles, rectangles (in case of 2d) and spheres, octahedrons (in case of 3d). And all these classes have methods, some in common, some not. This should determine where those methods are defined.

Comment: Look into the concept of composition over inheritance - very relevant here (but perhaps beyond the scope of the homework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Vehicle(object):
    #class variable shared between all instances of objects. 
    number_of_vehicles = 0 

    def __init__(self,length,width,color,wheels):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        Vehicle.number_of_vehicles += 1 #increasing class varaible count

    def get_length(self):
        print("I am %d meters long!"%self.length)

    def get_wdith(self):
        print("I am %d meters wide!"%self.width)

    def get_color(self):
        print("My color is %s!"%self.color)

    def get_wheels(self):
        print("I have %d number of wheels"%self.wheels)

    #calling my methods so I don't need to call each of their own
    def get_stats(self):
        self.get_length()
        self.get_wheels()
        self.get_wdith()
        self.get_color()

    def honk(self):
        print("beep beep")

class Car(Vehicle):
    def vroom(self):
        print("Cars go vroom vroom")

class Cooper(Car):
    def drift(self):
        print("Mini Coopers can drift well")

class Airplanes(Vehicle):
    def fly(self):
        print("weeeeee I'm flying")

class Tank(Vehicle):
    #custom init because tanks have guns!~ 
    #taking the gun size and tossing the rest of the arguments to the parent. 
    #if the parent doesn't find a __init__ it will keep going up until one is found or unelss we call it. 
    #Here we made a new __init__ so it doesn't go looking for one, but we call super() which is calling for the 
    #parent's __init__
    def __init__(self,gun_size,*args):
        self.gun_size = gun_size
        super(Tank,self).__init__(*args)
    def fire(self):
        print("pew pew pew")

    #I have my custom get_stats but still calls parent's one so I don't repeat code.
    def get_stats(self):
        print("my gun is this big: %d " %self.gun_size)
        super(Tank,self).get_stats()

a = Cooper(150,150,"blue",4)
a.drift()
a.vroom()
a.honk()
a.get_stats()
print(a.number_of_vehicles)

b = Airplanes(200,150,"white",2)
b.fly()
print(b.number_of_vehicles)

c = Tank(500,500,250,"Green",18)
c.fire()
print(c.number_of_vehicles)
c.get_stats()
```

Outputs:

```
Mini Coopers can drift well
Cars go vroom vroom
beep beep
I am 150 meters long!
I have 4 number of wheels
I am 150 meters wide!
My color is blue!
1                     #vehicle count
weeeeee I'm flying    # start of plan section
2                     #vehicle count
pew pew pew           #start of tank section
3                     #vehicle count
my gun is this big: 500  
I am 500 meters long!
I have 18 number of wheels
I am 250 meters wide!
My color is Green!
```

So the point of this post was to show you relationship of inheritance.

We have a base class called `Vehicle` which is a sub class of `object`. Don't worry about `object` if you want you can read up on it.

Vehicle class has some attibutes that all vehicles would have, length, width, color, wheels. It also have a class variable called `number_of_vehicles` which keeps track of how many object instances Vehicle has, basically how many Vehicles we "made". We also have some class methods, that access and uses the attributes we defined in `__init__`. You can do math on them and what not but for now we are just using them as print statements to show they work. We have a special class method that calls other methods in the same class. So `get_stats` calls the other `get_x` methods in the instance. This allows me to call those 4 methods with just "one" method call from my object, see `a.get_stats()`. We can still call the other methods on it's own like `get_color`.

We have a sub class called Car which is a vehicle, so we inherit it. Only cars can go vroom, but all cars can go vroom so we have a vroom method only at the car level. The trick is to think what does this class have that is unique to only instances of this class, and if not, can I put it in the parent's class. All vehicles have wheels and so on, but not all vehicles can go vroom (for this example only).

We have a sub class of Car, the cooper (mini cooper), which only it can drift (once again for this example only in real life the drift method would go in vehicle cause all vehicles can draft but bear with me). So this cooper is the only car that can drift so it's down here instead of in the Car class.

Tank's sub class is interesting. Here we have the basic of a vehicle but we have something new, a gun! So our vehicle class can't handle a gun, so we have to make a new `__init__` method. We assign the object variable `gun_size` and then pass the rest of the tank's attribute to Vehicle's `__init__` since the rest of the attributes are the same as Vehicle. We call `super(Tank,self).__init__(*args)` which is basically saying, I am a tank, this is me, please handle the rest of my attribute, parent of mine. Since tanks have a special attribute of a gun, we have to modify our `get_stats` method, to deal with the `gun_size` attribute, but the rest of the stats on the tank are the same as vehicle, so we just call our parents to handle the rest after we deal with our gun.

Now I know this is a very silly example, but I do hope you find some useful information in here. There are other majors points I haven't touched upon but this is a starting point. So back to your original question. Think abstract, the highest level would be a shape, then Rectangles are a type of shape so they would inherit it. Squares are special rectangles, so they would inherit rectangles and so on.

If you have questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I do not want to give answers that are too specific, because homework, but here is an example which I think might orient you in the right direction.

In Object Oriented Programming, there is the concept of polymorphism: when instances of many different subclasses are related by some common superclass. You often see it explained as "a B is an A", like in "a Pear is a Fruit", "a Cat is an Animal", "a Triangle is a Shape". Subclasses all share a common set of methods and members present in the superclass, but their implementation of these methods can vary.

Here is an example (sorry, C style, not a Python person) with animals. The method hearNoise() accepts an animal, but will also work correctly if a subtype is passed to it:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract String makeNoise();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    String makeNoise() {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String makeNoise() {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

void hearNoise(Animal a) {
    println(a.makeNoise());
}

int main() {
    hearNoise(new Cat()); //returns "Meow!"
    hearNoise(new Dog()); //returns "Woof!"
}
```

The same principles can be applied to geometric shapes. They all have common methods and members : their perimeter, their area, their color, etc. When you have a shape, you can expect with 100% certitude you will be able to call a method to calculate a perimeter. However, the implementation, the way that specific shape subclass handles perimeter calculation, is what differs from shape to shape.

Answer (score 1):

One of the big ideas of using inheritance is to be able to re-use code.. If you have a large body of functions that are the same for several classes, having one parent class that holds those functions allows you to only write them once, and to modify them all at the same time. for example, if you want to implement classes for the shapes: Square, Rectangle, and Parallelogram, you could create a parent class: Quadrangle that contains things like a generic area or perimeter functions:

```python
class quadrangle(object):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*self.length + 2*self.width

class square(quadrangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super(square, self).__init__(length, length) #creates a quadrangle with equal lenght and width

class rectangle(quadrangle): #renamed for convienience sake but otherwise the same
    pass

class parallelogram(quadrangle):
    def __init__(self, length, width, angle): #angle in radians
        self.angle = angle
        super(parallelogram, self).__init__(length, width)

    def perimeter(self): #override parent's perimiter
        #do some math
        return 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the Shapes class. In the __init__ , you have to set the attributes. First you need 2 parameters other than self. You can use the same names as the attributes or pick different names.

```
class Shapes(attributes):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
```

If you want to inherit from Shapes class, other than putting it in () in 2dShapes class definition, you have to call the __init__ of the Shapes class and pass a reference and other parameters to it, like this:

```
class 2dShapes(Shapes):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        Shapes.__init__(self, length, width)
```

If you want to use a method of Shapes in 2dShapes, you have to call it just like how we did for the __init__, lets say there is a method called area() in Shapes. In the 2dShapes, you can access it by Shapes.area(self). Here is an example:

```
class Shapes(attributes):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

class 2dShapes(Shapes):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        Shapes.__init__(self, length, width)
    def area(self):
        return Shapes.area(self)
```

Comment: You *don't* have to `def __init__` in 2dShapes, it will go up to the parents if it doesn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful not to confuse "attributes" with "methods". There is an @property syntax which wraps attribute access within a method call, but you should ignore that for now.

```
class Shapes(attributes):
    def __init__(self):
```

For this part, just absorb the arguments here. e.g:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Reason being, that you are only using Shapes to pass them to a subclass. `*args` absorbs lists of named arguments, while `**kwargs` absorbs dictionaries. So this `init()` will accept `my_shapes_instance = Shapes(length, width, height)` because it has `*args`, and it would accept `Shapes(length, width, height, {'cost': '10'})` because it has `**kwargs` as well.

If it were `__init__(length, width, height)` and you passed `(length, width, height, color)` then it would not work. But if you use `*args` then it will accept anything. Will it *use* all of these arguments? Only if you define that it does.

You can ignore **kwargs for now since you are not initializing these objects with dictionaries.

```
attributes.__init__(self)
        # not sure how to go on to make the attributes like height and length, radius ect. Maybe like this???

    def height(self):
        raise NotImplementedError # again this program is not supose to actually do anything. The program is just for us to understand inheritance with classes and super classes.
```

What you have done above is define a method "height", not an *attribute* "height". What you want is more like this:

```
def __init__(self, height):
    self.height = height
```

Even better is this, but do it in the Square subclass:

```
class Square(Shapes):
    def __init__(self, height, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Square, self).__init__(height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.height = height
```

Now you can subclass Square with Rectangle, adding in new args as you go.  Just follow a similar **init** pattern as above. Rectangle will not need you to add a height method, since it is already available from the parent.